# how can i make the response of the HTTP Request here public to other functions? (Swift)

Tags: swift

so i have this code here

```
    let url = URL(string: APILink)!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        let response = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        print(response)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

i was wondering how i could make `response` here public to other functions?
using the `public` keyword when declaring `response` doesnt work (of course)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that response is private, but that it is a local variable. It is similar to

```
func foobar() {
  let x = 3 // local variable, no one else can access this!
}
```

the simplest solution is to figure out where else you want access to that variable and pass it as a parameter

```
func needsX(passedInX x: Int) {
  // do something with x
}

func foobar() {
  let x = 3 // local variable, no one else can access this!
  needsX(passedInX: x) // now it can access x
}
```

Alternatives to passing it as a parameter would be to save in another variable which has a broader scope, for example an instance variable (if you are inside a class)

```
func foobar() {
  let x = 3 // local variable, no one else can access this!
  self.x = 3 // now any method in this instance can access it via self.x
}
```